# PHP CodeIgniter Ion Auth Creating a New Group

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth, codeigniter-helpers

I am building a website and am new to Codeigniter and Ion Auth. My website consists of three tiers of user: regular user, moderator and admin. I understand is_admin and is_logged in, but can't figure out how to create a new group for my moderators.

Ideally, I would like to use something like this to protect my moderator pages:

```
if (!$this->ion_auth->in_group('moderator'))
{
    //redirect them to the home page because they must be an administrator to view this
    redirect($this->config->item('base_url'), 'refresh');
}
```

How can I create a new group of user for my moderators? Is it something I need to do in my database? I've seen code in the documentation but am not sure where/how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either manually add the group to the `groups` table of your db - I guess this is easiest for you as you probably only need to do it once - or  you could use the method `create_group()` built into the library:

```
 $this->ion_auth->create_group('moderator', 'This is the moderators group');
```

Then you will be able to check your users as you suggest.

Comment: Thank you for you quick response, but unfortunately I'm still puzzled!

Comment: Please tell me what need clarification. Your question is "How can I create a new group of user for my moderators?" What is unclear? How to add a row in your `groups` table? How to use the suggested code?